# Water heater pilot goes out after a burn cycle

Tags: water-heater, natural-gas, pilot-light, thermocouple

Having the issue of having to relight the pilot after ever burn cycle. I cleaned the thermocouple, lit the pilot, and watched a burn cycle through the window. This is when I noticed something strange; when the burner lights it’s a strong flame that goes straight up like it’s supposed to, but after a few seconds, it’s like there is a draft from somewhere and the burner flame gets blown down and spread out causing the pilot flame to do the same which causes the thermocouple to cool and when the burner shuts off so does the pilot because there was not enough flame to keep the thermocouple hot.
What could be causing this draft, or whatever makes it seem like a draft, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like a loss of pressure on the gas perhaps. Where does the gas come from? Is it in a bottle/tank? Can you link to a video of the behavior?

Comment: This could be a misaligned flue.  I had a broadly similar problem a few years ago, refitting the flue fixed it.

Comment: Had a small propane furnace/heater with the intake/exhaust though the wall.  Every time the wind blew right it, would put out the pilot light.  Sometimes it was hard to re-light with the wind.